# python 2.7 bcrypt not found after pip already satisfied

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, bcrypt

```
me@localhost:# sudo pip install bcrypt
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): bcrypt in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cffi>=1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from bcrypt)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.4.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from bcrypt)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from cffi>=1.1->bcrypt)
Cleaning up...
me@localhost:# python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Mar 19 2017, 23:18:21) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bcrypt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named bcrypt
```

Why does pip say bcrypt is there when it obviously isn't? Lies!

Python 3 doesn't have access to it either.

```
me@localhost:# python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 17 2016, 01:08:31) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bcrypt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'bcrypt'
```

So I guess pip is just unreliable?

Comment: What does 'which python' return? Maybe it's not the same Python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

The command is now `pip install python-bcrypt` after looking at the README.md [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-bcrypt) (in the tar.gz after extracting).

It would be nice if someone updated [these](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bcrypt/2.0.0) docs.

Comment: those seem to be two separate libraries that both provide a `bcrypt` module